# Printing SInhala Unicode letters to Epson TMU220D printer

Tags: java, unicode

We are trying to take a printout from a POS printer using Epson Javapos ADK. (MODEL : EPSON TMU220D) the printout prints in English with out any problem. But when we try to print Sinhala Unicode letters to the printer it prints as "?" marks. We are feeding data (Sinhala words) to the printer as Unicode letters. We can't quite figure out how to sort this out. Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Here is the code that we're using.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c4858f19cb474be76b7

Comment: This probably has to do with the fonts available on the device, and whether or not it supports Unicode.  I took a quick look at the programming guide (could only find the one for the TM-T20) and it looks like it uses ASCII code pages instead of Unicode, and there is no Sinhala page listed.  This printer may not be usable for your purpose, but you will probably have to contact Epson support to verify this.

Comment: Thank you Jim for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jim mentioned, TM-U220 does not support the UNICODE as internal font. That why it print "?". 
If the "Sinhala words" which you want to print are limited, there are alternative solution.
TM-U220 printer has open code page, Page254 and Page255, you can put your font data at those open code Page.
Epson has tool, "TM FontRunner" it will help to put your font data at Page254 and Page255.
https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4968&pcat=5&pid=42